# Adding new value to List remains parts of previous value

Tags: c#, list, split

I have obtained from `url` a string from the following form:

```
450,2277,687005562
13331,99,21042886
8023,99,21054328
```

When I try to add the values into a list like this:

```
List<string> splitted = new List<string>();
string fileList = results;
string[] tempStr;
tempStr = fileList.Split(new Char[] {'\n',','});
int j = 0;
foreach (string item in tempStr)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
    {
        splitted.Add(item);
        Console.Write(splitted[j]);
        Console.ReadKey();
        j++;
    }
}
```

The results I obtain are:

450, 2277, 687005562 and then 133315562 which is a combination of 13331 and the last digits of the previous number because it was longer.

How can I just add each value into its cell?

Thank you.

Comment: You're writing all the output on the same line, so each line overlaps the previous one. Try using WriteLine() intsead of Write(), and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: That did the job..Thank mate.

Comment: @BBen keep in mind you can simplify your logic a bit: `List<string> splitted = fileList.Split(new Char[] {'\n',','}).ToList();` This will give you a list directly instead of moving into the temp variable `tempStr`

Comment: Or just: `results.Split('\n', ',').ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using Write() instead of WriteLine()

Try this.

```
List<string> splitted = new List<string>();
string fileList = results;
string[] tempStr;

tempStr = fileList.Split(new Char[] {'\n',','});
int j = 0;
foreach (string item in tempStr)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
    {
        splitted.Add(item);
        Console.WriteLine(splitted[j]);
        Console.ReadKey();
        j++;
    }
}
```